# AndroidX: Set Enter key to validate EditTextPreference dialog box

Tags: android, androidx, appcompatactivity, edittextpreference, imeoptions

I'm trying to make a preference screen with **AndroidX**, but I'm encountering a small problem...

When I validate my entry with the "OK" button on the virtual keyboard, the preference is not validated. (keyboard is hidden, that's all...)

With AndroidX, we can no longer override `showDialog()` in `EditTextPreference`... and I couldn't find another way to access the dialog box to dismiss it.

In conclusion, what I wish: the DONE action of the button on the virtual keyboard validates the AlertDialog.

[image]

Here's my sample code:

*XML file*

```xml
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <EditTextPreference
        app:key="pref_1"
        app:title="Test"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" /> 
</PreferenceScreen>
```

*Preference activity*

```java
public class MySettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {

    [...]

    public static class HeaderFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.header_preferences, rootKey);

            EditTextPreference pref1 = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("pref_1");
            pref1.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to validate that update value of text you need to use this listener

```
pref1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                // put validation here..

                Log.d("Prefrence====>",newValue+"<===  validate you can validate this value");

                return true; //if you pass false here the updated value will not save
            }
        });
```

here is the example to use the true false return

```
public static class HeaderFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.headerpref, rootKey);

        EditTextPreference pref1 = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("pref_1");

        pref1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                // put validation here..

                Log.d("Prefrence====>",newValue+"<===  validate you can validate this value");
                if(newValue.toString().length()>0){
                    return  true;
                }else return false;
            }
        });

        pref1.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        //Your dialog will dissmiss on ok click
                        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)dismissDialog();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
        });


    }
void dismissDialog(){
        for(Fragment fragments : HeaderFragment.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){
            if(fragments instanceof EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat){
                EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat dialog = ((EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat) fragments);
                dialog.onDialogClosed(true);
                dialog.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you want to dismiss Dialog manually you can do it like this way , cause there are no direct method available to get the dialog and dismiss it.

*I updated the dialog dismiss listener as your need to save the data passing true in **onDialogClosed** method will help to save your data*

```
void dismissDialog(){

        for(Fragment fragments : HeaderFragment.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){
            if(fragments instanceof EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat){
                EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat dialog = ((EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat) fragments);
                dialog.onDialogClosed(true);
                dialog.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, It doesn't work. onPreferenceChange is not triggered on the "OK" of the virtual keyboard

Comment: updated code now you can dismiss it on keyboard done click , please find code for it mark accepted .

Comment: It works! Thank you! I also found a way to do that. I'll put it below (but i dont really like the way I do it)

Comment: Yes , but what can we do , now in androidx they took all control from us for dialog , earlier there are positive button was there with edittextprefrences

Comment: There's still a problem: with dismiss function, preference is not saved. To do this in you example, we can call the `callOnClick` function from the AlertDialog : `((AlertDialog)((EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat) fragments).getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).callOnClick();`

Comment: I updated the dismiss method according to your need , if you /anybody want to use

Answer (score 1):

I found another way. I don't think it's the best, but if it can help anyone...

*PreferenceFragmentCompat customized*

```java
public class PreferenceFragmentCompatCustom extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    private static final String DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG =
            "androidx.preference.PreferenceFragment.DIALOG";
    private DialogFragment mDialogFragment;

    @Override
    public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
        if (getActivity() instanceof MySettingsActivity) {
            final DialogFragment f;
            if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
                f = EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.newInstance(preference.getKey());
            } else if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                f = ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.newInstance(preference.getKey());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tried to display dialog for unknown " +
                        "preference type. Did you forget to override onDisplayPreferenceDialog()?");
            }
            f.setTargetFragment(this, 0);

            // Expose the dialog
            mDialogFragment = f;

            f.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        }else{
            super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
        }
    }

    public DialogFragment getDialog(){ return mDialogFragment;}

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {}
}
```

*Preference activity*

```
public class MySettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {

    [...]

    public static class HeaderFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompatCustom {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.header_preferences, rootKey);

            EditTextPreference pref1 = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("pref_1");
            pref1.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

                    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                                // If callOnClick, do not save value here
                                //etpTest.setText(v.getText().toString());
                                // If dismiss, the preference is not set !
                                //getDialog().dismiss();

                                ((AlertDialog) getDialog().getDialog())
                                               .getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                                               .callOnClick();
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: f.setTargetFragment() is deprecated. It says you should use a FragmentResultListener.